# getAction Bar gives null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i want to work with action bar in android. 
for this i use

```
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

below the SetContentView . but is gives me null pointer exception. 
when i try only getActionBar() it works fine.

please help me.

Comment: can you post your `manifest` file and more code?

Comment: Silly question, but does your activity _have_ an ActionBar? If not, that'd explain it since that'd make `getActionBar()` return null.

Comment: Post your code of activity and your manifest's code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your activity does not have a `title bar` the method `getActionBar()` can return null.

You have two options to fix this:

1- Add `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);` before `setContentView`

2- In your `Manifest` specify a Theme that supports `ActionBar`

Also make sure that you are targeting the right android version e.g. `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" />`

Comment: getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR); is works perfect. thanks a lot.

Comment: @vivektiwari but it is much better practice to apply a theme to your app android:Theme.Holo or android:Theme.Holo.Light.

Answer (score 0):

getActionBar() will return null for pre Honeycomb devices.

If you are targeting Android v2.3 to 4.2 try out [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com).