# Null pointer errors in mainActivity for building swipe view with tabs on Android studios

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-viewpager, swipeview

I am looking to build the swipe view with tabs function in my application by following a tutorial that I found on one of the answers in the forum

[http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/]

But I keep getting a null pointer error which I cant seem to find out why? I have strictly followed the tutorial and also read other similar questions about swipe views on forum. The coding are practically identical to what I have at the moment. But every time I run the emulator I get this error

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tim.swipe/com.example.tim.swipe.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActionBar$Tab android.app.ActionBar.newTab()' on a null object reference
```

I assume its something to do with the ActionBar but the codes from the tutorial and other sources are practically the same.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {



ViewPager viewPager;
TabsPagerAdapter adapter;
ActionBar actionBar;
String[] tabs =  { "FragmentA", "FragmentB", "FragmentC" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}




@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

TabsPageAdapter.java

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {

    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            // Top Rated fragment activity
            return new FragmentA();
        case 1:
            // Games fragment activity
            return new FragmentB();
        case 2:
            // Movies fragment activity
            return new FragmentC();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

FragmentA

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {


public FragmentA() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
```

FragmentB and FragmentC has the same code except for their layouts.

Comment: post your code, so we can see where the error is happening

Comment: No i cant see what is in MainActivity because you haven't posted your code, post it please

Answer (score 0):

Add this variable to the Class:

```
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
```

Change your onCreate method to this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(actionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: It says error saying "Cannot resolve method 'getSupportActionBar();'

Comment: I have added that but I still get the same error message. Also It says that setNavigationMode is deprecated. I am using API level 21 for compilation if that's of any help

Comment: I have changed from **FragmentActivity** to**ActionBarActivity** and then used `actionBar = getSupportedActionBar();` This allowed the application to run which seems to have bypassed the java.lang null pointer problem. But now I have the problem where when swipe to a next fragment, the aciton bar on top doesn't change along with it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too.
Here is a solution it is works for me.

**Add**

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
```

**Before**

```
setContentView
```

Make sure that  your Themes in `Manifest` that's support Action Bar.

Also make sure your Android  minsdkversion above 11.

Hope this would work for you.

You can refer this original answer below.
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871022/getaction-bar-gives-null-pointer-exception?answertab=votes#tab-top)