# Android Fragmnet activity from Fragment.Noe in Fragment Activity getting nullpointer exception on getActionBar()

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I am starting Fragment Activity from Fragment...
Now in Fragment Activity I need

```
android.app.ActionBar mainactionbar = getActionBar();
mainactionbar.setIcon(R.drawable.sq_mobile);
```

But in above line `mainactionbar.setIcon(R.drawable.sq_mobile);` i am getting `Null Pointer Exception`

What i can do for this?

Comment: try getSupportActionBar();

Comment: no i need to extend only fragment activity

Comment: @anirudh no i am not able to write getSupportActionBar()

Comment: you may check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871022/getaction-bar-gives-null-pointer-exception

Comment: use getSupportActionBar(); & check YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity